# What is the relation between the quantity of information of $A_i$ and $A$, where $A=\bigcup_iA_i$?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, mathematical-foundations

Let $A$ be an event divided into 4 events $A_i$ with the same probability. Why does the quantity of information of $A_i$ satisfy
$$ I(A_i) = I(A) + \log (4)?$$

Comment: What does $I(A)$ stand for?

Comment: I(A) = -P(A) x log(P(A))

Comment: Your equation doesn't seem to hold for your formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the correct formula is
$$
I(A) = \log \frac{1}{\Pr[A]}.
$$

In this case, we have
$$
I(A_i) = \log \frac{4}{\Pr[A]} = \log \frac{1}{\Pr[A]} + \log 4 = I(A) + \log 4.
$$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. But why for X  a random variable with the probability distribution p1, ...pn, and Y with the probability distribution (p1)/4,....(pn)/4, we have the same relation H(X)=H(Y)+log(4) ?

Comment: Not that you've seen what calculation you need to do, I encourage you to try again on your own.

Comment: Also, you can try to use the chain rule in some way.

Comment: I tried but I got a different result. H(Y) =  -ΣP(Y=k) x log(P(Y=K)) = -Σpk/4x log(pk/4) = H(X)/4 + Σpk/4 x log(4)= H(X) /4+ log(4)/4 x Σpk = H(X) /4+ log(4)/4

Comment: Well then, perhaps a different relation holds.